# div:hover is affecting all elements below

Tags: jquery, html, css, hover

Here is a sample fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/K2zyU/4/

The problem I am experiencing is that the main navigation hover is applying to the sub navigation items. If for example, I were to move the list above the main navigation div the hover works as I would expect? I'm unsure of what I'm missing / doing wrong in this case.

```
<div class="main">MAIN NAV<div>
<ul class="sub">
    <li>SUB NAV 1</li>
    <li>SUB NAV 2</li>
    <li>SUB NAV 3</li>
    <li>SUB NAV 4</li>
    <li>SUB NAV 5</li>
    <li>SUB NAV 6</li>
</ul>

.main:hover, .sub li:hover {
    color: black;
    background-color: #f3ffff;
    opacity: .6;
}
```

​
​
​
​

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is this line

```
<div class="main">MAIN NAV<div>
```

You haven't closed the `div`, so the list is a child of that div. It should be

```
<div class="main">MAIN NAV</div>
```

Comment: Yep. Simple problem. Simple solution. Sometimes hard to find.

Answer (score 3):

You are missing `/`

```
<div class="main">MAIN NAV</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/K2zyU/11/

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to close your `main` div. Try this:

```
<div class="main">MAIN NAV</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is the effect you are looking for http://jsfiddle.net/shivkumarganesh/K2zyU/5/ actually when you are trying to merge the two menus using the .main:hover,.sub li:hover the effects are applied to the main div as a whole and only the text color of the sub menu changes rather than the background. I fixed it in the above fiddle.